# QR Code generator problem with missing white spaces

Tags: qr-code

When generating QR Code using spaces, after scanning it with phone there are missing spaces. For any other character including non-breaking space (alt + 255) it works corectly. Problem is customer only allows whitespaces and needs correct length of acquired string from the qr code.

So how to reproduce this problem:
https://www.qr-code-generator.com/ and there generate qrcode with this input

```
20201104                2011041609830000                                        TEST                               000001000000000000019.000                    450368923400010Z20000Z1010N-3N36                                   1.000EA      450368923400020Z20000Z1010N-3N18                                   1.000EA      450368923400030Z20000Z1010N-3N20                                   1.000EA      450368923400040Z20000Z1010N-3N22                                   1.000EA      450368923400050Z20000Z1010N-3N24                                   1.000EA      450368923400060Z20000Z1010N-3N26                                   1.000EA      450368923400070Z20000Z1010N-3N27                                   1.000EA      450368923400080Z20000Z1010N-3N30                                   1.000EA      450368923400090Z20000Z1010N-3N34                                   1.000EA      450368923400100Z20000Z1010N-3N13                                   1.000EA
```

After scanning this the string acquired is this form:

```
20201104                2011041609830000                                        TEST                              000001000000000000019.000                    450368923400010Z20000Z1010N-3N36                                  1.000EA      450368923400020Z20000Z1010N-3N18                                  1.000EA      450368923400030Z20000Z1010N-3N20                                  1.000EA      450368923400040Z20000Z1010N-3N22                                  1.000EA      450368923400050Z20000Z1010N-3N24                                  1.000EA      450368923400060Z20000Z1010N-3N26                                  1.000EA      450368923400070Z20000Z1010N-3N27                                  1.000EA      450368923400080Z20000Z1010N-3N30                                  1.000EA      450368923400090Z20000Z1010N-3N34                                  1.000EA      450368923400100Z20000Z1010N-3N13                                  1.000EA
```

The length is decreased by 1 between starting from TEST until end, resulting in loss of about 10 white spaces

Replicating this with any other characters, example:

```
20201104################2011041609830000########################################TEST###############################000001000000000000019.000####################450368923400010Z20000Z1010N-3N36 ##################################1.000EA #####450368923400020Z20000Z1010N-3N18 ##################################1.000EA #####450368923400030Z20000Z1010N-3N20 ##################################1.000EA #####450368923400040Z20000Z1010N-3N22 ##################################1.000EA #####450368923400050Z20000Z1010N-3N24 ##################################1.000EA #####450368923400060Z20000Z1010N-3N26 ##################################1.000EA #####450368923400070Z20000Z1010N-3N27 ##################################1.000EA #####450368923400080Z20000Z1010N-3N30 ##################################1.000EA #####450368923400090Z20000Z1010N-3N34 ##################################1.000EA #####450368923400100Z20000Z1010N-3N13 ##################################1.000EA #####
```

Results in this after scanning the qr code:

```
20201104################2011041609830000########################################TEST###############################000001000000000000019.000####################450368923400010Z20000Z1010N-3N36 ##################################1.000EA #####450368923400020Z20000Z1010N-3N18 ##################################1.000EA #####450368923400030Z20000Z1010N-3N20 ##################################1.000EA #####450368923400040Z20000Z1010N-3N22 ##################################1.000EA #####450368923400050Z20000Z1010N-3N24 ##################################1.000EA #####450368923400060Z20000Z1010N-3N26 ##################################1.000EA #####450368923400070Z20000Z1010N-3N27 ##################################1.000EA #####450368923400080Z20000Z1010N-3N30 ##################################1.000EA #####450368923400090Z20000Z1010N-3N34 ##################################1.000EA #####450368923400100Z20000Z1010N-3N13 ##################################1.000EA #####
```

Which is exactly as the input string and works correctly.

Every qr generator we tried online or programatically does exact same thing with spaces.

Has anybody came across this problem / knows why is this happening?

Answer (score 1):

proof: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LRXV6.png

I tried here - https://setools.xyz/qr-code-generator/ Unable to replicate the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Your link doesn't seem to work (suspended domain) so I can't try that. Have you tried https://www.qr-code-generator.com/ and got the same result as yours or as mine?

Comment: Yes, I don't know why they( qr-code-generator.com ) are trimming the spaces but the website https://setools.xyz/qr-code-generator/  was working before 30 mins,  I will check it after some time.

Comment: What about these two? https://www.the-qrcode-generator.com/ http://goqr.me/ for me both trimmed white spaces.

Comment: this works fine for me - http://goqr.me/
I'm getting exact chars

Comment: Well I don't understand this, I tried http://goqr.me/ 10 times in a row and got missing white spaces every single time... This is baffling to me, maybe it's regional? Like if you from US and use the URL you get different results than Europe (CZ)

Comment: I don't think so, how do you getting values from qr code? try changing the way of getting the values.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228966/discussion-between-karpi-and-iamqwasyx0).

Comment: I use QR Reader #1 on Appstore but tried like 5 more and still getting the same results... Anyways thanks so much for help.

Answer (score 0):

So after some digging I came to this conclusion: The qr code is correct, but the app (apps) in appstore generate wrong output when sent to email.

So steps to reproduce after scanning qr code are:

Sending result to email results in losing spaces in output.

Copying result to clipboard results in correct output.

This issue can be reproduced on most downloaded qrcodes on app store.